# configuration of ejabberd database to mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd from command line on ubuntu 12.04,
Now, I want to change ejabberd default database to mysql. 
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

A good reference is provided by ejabberd's [Installation and Operation Guide](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/doc/guide.html), at chapter [MySQL](https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#htoc33).

In brief, you need to build ejabberd with mysql support ('./configure --enable-odbc && make install'), then for each module you want to use with mysq, change the related part in ejabberd.cfg.

For example, you'll use 'mod_roster_odbc' instead of ['mod_roster'](https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#modroster).
The actual strategy depends on your specific configuration, and what you want to move to MySQL (from the default Mnesia) or keep in Mnesia.

You'll find the sql queries to build the DB and all the tables inside ejabberd's source repository.

Take also into account that if you're using ejabberd in a cluster, then you still need Mnesia for a minimum set of tables (e.g. 'schema') in order to allow the Erlang nodes to connect to each other and keep in synch.

Comment: you should also add that the ejabberd.cfg should be changed in order to provide odbc support

Comment: That's a useful additional information, however it's covered in the "MySQL" chapter I linked above. It mentions the changes needed in the configuration file, and also the dependency on the Erlang MySQL library. The [link contained inside that section](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver), unfortunately unavailable at the moment, contains further useful details.